# book about string theory a la Von Neumann

Tags: reference-request, mp.mathematical-physics, string-theory

Can we summarize string theory (in its actual state) in some principles and fundamental equations like electromagnetism, general relativity, quantum mechanics and classical mechanics ?

I am looking for a book for string theory for mathematicians similar to the book of Von Neumann for QM.

Comment: @NeilStrickland Thanks!  could you write down the equations of string theory in a clear way reading those books ?

Comment: String theory is just not at that mature stage yet. A non-perturbative definition is unavailable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a book, but an informative and enjoyable summary has been given by Robbert Dijkgraaf:

[The mathematics of string theory](http://www.bourbaphy.fr/dijkgraaf.pdf)

> String theory can be considered as a two-parameter deformation of
>   classical geometry, where one parameter controls the generalization
>   from points to loops, and the other parameter controls the
>   quantization in terms of the sum over topologies of Riemann surfaces.
>   The final formulation of non-perturbative string theory, which is not
>   yet there, will have to bring together geometry, non-commutative
>   algebra and loop spaces.